# Retrieving search scopes from current site collection

Tags: 2010, development, error, search-scope

I've did some research on Internet and found some code examples how to retrieve search scopes, but when I try to execute it fails, what do I do wrong?

Here is the code:

```
  SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
  SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchServiceAppProxy = serviceContext.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
  SearchServiceApplicationInfo searchSerivceAppInfo = searchServiceAppProxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo();
  SearchServiceApplication searchServiceApplication = SearchService.Service.SearchApplications.GetValue<SearchServiceApplication>(searchSerivceAppInfo.SearchServiceApplicationId);
  Scopes scopes = new Scopes(searchServiceApplication);
  foreach (Scope scope in scopes.GetSharedScopes())
  {
      scopeList.Add(scope);
  }
```

Ok in this case I try to get SharedScopes but in general I just need to get all scopes, if i do scopes.AllScopes it doesnt work.

I checked the Log files and it seems I get an error there, some error that says, fail to connect to database and so on and so on. And it happens exactly on the like where i do scopes.AllScopes (or scopes.GetSharedScopes()) and so on). Do I miss something? I even tried to run this code with elevated privileges, but that doesn't help. Still the same error.

So what do I miss?

Update:
I don't know, I suppose that that account has enought rights as it is systemaccount, here is the error:

> Cannot open database
>   "Search_Service_Application_DB_71f6d22eda5e4eecbc4e225360b2d5a6"
>   requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user
>   'sp2010appweb'.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection)     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj)....

Comment: What kind of account are you using?  Does the account have enough access to work with the service application?  Can you post the entire error?

Comment: Updated teh question with error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution instead of using the SearchServiceApplication which causes the issues with permissions, I use this piece of code:

```
RemoteScopes remoteScopes = new RemoteScopes(SPServiceContext.GetContext(site));
```

And it works like a charm.